# call function by name

Tags: applescript

*Given*: script with multiple functions in it (see below)
*Wanted*: call a function by name from command line, e.g. `osascript lib.scpt fn1`
*Problem*: Executing the above command gives "lib.scpt: execution error: «script» doesn't understand the argv message. (-1708)"

How can I call a function by name?

---

```
on run argv
    argv() // <-- here's the problem
end run

on fn0()
    return "hello from fn0"
end fn0

on fn1()
    return "hello from fn1"
end fn1
```

Comment: You include the call to `argv` but the actual method doesn't exist, hence why you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found what you're looking for [on MacScripter](http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?pid=36526#p36526):

```
on run argv
    set arg to (item 1 of argv)
    set scpt to "on run inArgs\n(item 1 of inArgs)'s " & arg & "()\n\tend"

    run script scpt with parameters {me}

end run

on fn0()
    return "hello from fn0"
end fn0

on fn1()
    return "hello from fn1"
end fn1
```